# Network printer used on multiple platforms?

Tags: networking, network-printer

I have an HP M251nw.  It is currently connected to a wired network with certain securities for business purposes.

We also have a separate wireless network that it can connect to as well for laptops and tablets to use.

Can anyone tell me if it can be wired to one network and wireless on another network?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. This is a good question, only lacking in the details of what you have researched or attempted in order to resolve this so far. In other words, have you tried to do what you are asking?

Comment: (i wont post it as an answer because is only a opinion) that should work, because both are independents adapters, but maybe the limitation is in the firmware is suggest you to check, there is not so many information from the hp support site.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [manual](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c02846659#129):

Page 117:

> Wireless connectivity checklist
>
> - Verify that the network cable is not connected
>
> ....

Based on this the answer is most likely "**No**", the manual recommends you to unplug the network cable if you are going to use wireless network.